# Share data between Fragment don't Update

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, share

I have 4 Fragment Sector1,2,3,4 and I would like to transfer data between Fragment.
When I add product in sector 1 , the same product are insert inside the Edit in the Sector2.
If I switch between Sector 1 and 2 no problem, but when I go to the Sector3 and I return to sector1 for insert another product , the new product don't appear in the Edit on the Sector2.
**Why? (this is the first Question)**, and I have implemented the same sharing data between Sector 1 and the Sector3 , but no product are added **Why? (this is the second question)**

Here the file:

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, 
                                                                OnShareMyDataListener{

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;  
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity.onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Settare il tipo di navigazione
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // creo icona e scritta per il 1 Tab
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("Ordine")
                .setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_agenda);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        // creo icona e scritta per il 2 Tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("by Mail")
                .setTabListener(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_send);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        // creo icona e scritta per il 3 Tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                 .setText("by SMS")
                 .setTabListener(this)
                 .setIcon(R.drawable.phone);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);      

        // creo icona e scritta per il 4 Tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                 .setText("Feedback")
                 .setTabListener(this)
                 .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_revert);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);      

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

// Il return new chiama le altre classi (i Fragment) 
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:                  
                    return new Sector1();

                case 1:
                    return new Sector2();

                case 2:
                    return new Sector3();

                case 3:
                    return new Sector4(); 

                default:                   
                    Fragment fragment = new Sector1();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();

                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    return fragment;
            }
        }

// Settare il titolo dei Sector
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onShareMyData(ArrayList<User> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Sector2 Sector2Obj = (Sector2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
         Sector2Obj.setMessage(data);   

         Sector3 Sector3Obj = (Sector3) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
         Sector3Obj.setMessage(data);
    }

}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

### Sector1.java

```
public class Sector1 extends Fragment 
{   
    private Button btnAggiungi;
    private EditText EtQta,EtName;

    ListView userList;

    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sector1, container, false);

            btnAggiungi = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_aggiungi);
            EtQta = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Et_qta);
            EtName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Et_name);

            btnAggiungi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
                    try {                           
                        String Qta = "Qtà: "+ String.valueOf(EtQta.getText());
                        String Prodotto = "prodotto: "+ String.valueOf(EtName.getText());

                        userArray.add(new User(Prodotto, Qta));

                        sharedData.onShareMyData(userArray);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                       
                }       
            });         

            //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
             return rootView;
        }

        OnShareMyDataListener sharedData;

        @Override
           public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
               super.onAttach(activity);
               try {
                   sharedData = (OnShareMyDataListener) activity/*getActivity()*/;
               } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                   throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onShareMyData");
               }
           }   


        /**
         * get datetime
         * */
        private String getDateTime() {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd/MM/yyyy kk:MM", Locale.getDefault());
            Date date = new Date();
            return dateFormat.format(date);
        }

        private String getItemUserArray() {
            String str=null;

            for (int i = 0; i < userArray.size(); i++) {
                str += userArray.get(i).toString();
             }
            return str;
        }

    }
```

### Sector2.java

```
public class Sector2 extends Fragment
{
    private Button btnSendOrder,btnBrowseContact;
    EditText nameField;
    EditText emailField;
    String subject = null;
    TextView txt;
    View rootView;
    private Spinner mySpinnerEmail;
    ArrayList<String> emailFornitore ;
    ArrayList<String> aEmailList;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sector2, container, false);
            init(rootView);

            return rootView;
        }


        void init(View rootView){


        }  
  /******************************************************************************/      


        void setMessage(ArrayList<User> data){
            String str;

            txt = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Et_ordine);

            str = "[" + data.get(0).getName() + "]\n";
            subject = str;
            for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
                str += data.get(i).getName() + "(" + data.get(i).getQta() + ")\n";
            }
            txt.setText(str);
        }


    }
```

### Sector3.java

```
public class Sector3 extends Fragment
{
    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textPhoneNo;
    EditText textSMS;
    TextView sms_count;
    String subject = null;
    TextView txt;
    View rootView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sector3, container, false);
            init(rootView);

            return rootView;
        }

        void init(View rootView){           

        } 

        void setMessage(ArrayList<User> data){
            String str;

            txt = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

            str = "[" + data.get(0).getName() + "]\n";// + data.get(0).getQta() + "]\n";
            subject = str;
            for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
                str += data.get(i).getName() + "(" + data.get(i).getQta() + ")\n";
            }
            txt.setText(str);
        }      


    }
```

### OnShareMyDataListener.java

```
public interface OnShareMyDataListener {
    public void onShareMyData(ArrayList<User> data);
}
```

### User.java

```
public class User {
     String name;
     String qta;

     public String getName() {
      return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
     }

     public String getQta() {
      return qta;
     }

     public void setQta(String qta) {
      this.qta = qta;
     }

     public User(String name, String qta) {
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.qta = qta;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What does **AppSectionPagerAdapter** extends ?
If you look in the [Android Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) you'll see that `FragmentPagerAdapter` **Destroy** the **view Hierachy** of your Fragment.
So when you go to section3, section1's view hierarchy is destroyed and when you go back, it is entirely reacreated but from scratch.

In your code the main problem is that the data you want to show are not stored. Keep in mind that in a Activity[Fragment[]] hierarchy the main point is the activity so you have to store your datas in the Activity to make it accessible from anywhere.

### My advice:

In your Activity add a field `ArrayList<User> data` who will be updated :

```
 @Override
    public void onShareMyData(ArrayList<User> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

And in your Sections's **onCreate()** :

```
sharedData = (OnShareMyDataListener) activity; 
sharedData.data
```